# Swift - how can I wait for dispatch_async finish?

Tags: multithreading, swift, core-data

When my app starts first time I perform task of importing data from disk into CoreData. I do thins in background thread. Then I switch to main thread and perform load from CoreData.

Problem is that sometimes load from CoreData occurs before import from disk is finished. So I need a way to wait for import to finish and only them perform load from db.

How can I do this in Swift?

My code looks like this:

```
func firstTimeLaunch() {

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(QOS_CLASS_USER_INTERACTIVE, 0)) { [unowned self] in

self.importArticlesListFromDisk()
self.importArticlesFromDisk()

       dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { [unowned self] in

       self.loadArticlesListFromDb()
       self.loadArticlesFromDb()

       }

   }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried loading your data at the end of the 'importArticlesFromDisk'?

Comment: Do `importArticlesListFromDisk` or `importArticlesFromDisk` make extra calls to `dispatch_async`? Because if not, your code looks like it would be fine.

Comment: If either of those two methods that Tom references are asynchronous, we can show you how to add a completion handler like subjective_c recommends. But we might need to see what those two methods look like in order to get more specific.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should try adding a completion handler to importArticlesListFromDisk and importArticlesFromDisk, then loading from the db in the completion block.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(QOS_CLASS_USER_INTERACTIVE, 0)) { [unowned self] in
    self.importArticlesAndArticlesListFromDisk() {
       // Completion Handler
       dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { [unowned self] in
           self.loadArticlesListFromDb()
           self.loadArticlesFromDb()
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using NSOperations. There is a great talk about this from [wwdc15](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015-226/)

The sample code is also quite interesting for that purpose.

Essentially, you want to create a concurrent operation for your each of your imports:

let's imagine we override the start function of an operation importing your article list from disk:

```
override func start {
    //long running import operation, even async...
    //when done: self.finish() //needs kvo overrides
    //finish causes the concurrent operation to terminate
}
```

A very nice thing you can do with operations, is to set dependencies:

```
let importArticlesFromDiskOp = ...
let importArticlesFromDBOp = ...

importArticlesFromDBOp.addDependency(importArticlesFromDiskOp)
```

This way your import from DB would only run after the import from disk is done. I personally use this a LOT.

good luck
R